# In Javascript, I need to access functioned scope var from block scope, I already have var with same name there

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I have two variables with same name, one is functional scoped and another is block scoped. I need access both variable from block scope.

Here's the code for that:

```
function myFunc(){  
    a = 10;
    console.log(a); // 10

    if(true){ 
        let a = 20;
        console.log(a); // 20
        console.log(a); // I need to access a with value 10 here...
    };
};

myFunc();
```

Comment: Just use different variable names and save yourself the confusion.

Comment: Don't write bad code and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a formal answer, shadowing is an intended feature of Javascript, so there is no way out of it.

You can always try and resolve the scope, for example (in browsers) defining `window.someVar` different than `someVar`as `someVar` can be shadowed but you can always explicitly write `window.someVar` anywhere in your code and refer to it  ...and/or using `this` when aplicable.

Below a working snippet for your example:

```js
function myFunc(){  
    a = 10;
    console.log(a); // 10

    if(true){ 
        let a = 20;
        console.log(a); // 20
        console.log(this.a); // 10 ... voit lá. Mind context of execution!
    };
};

myFunc();
```